# Apply F2 + Enter to all my cells in Excel 97-2003 with automatic micro in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I export a file from a software where I have many data,
I use an Excel template with different Tabs inside(Data, CO, NOx, ecc..), inside my software where i take the data from SQL Database.
When I try to export the xls file from my software, inside the Tab "Data" I have the updated data and in the other tabs like "CO" i have formulas and elaborations inside the cells that doesn't update automatically.

How can I have an updated cells in the "CO" Tab each time that I export a new file with different data in excel without pressing F2 + Enter to many cells?
Is there any simple and functional automatic micro in vba?

Comment: MAke sure Calculation mode is set to Automatic. Also, you can recalculate entire workbook pressing F9

Comment: Calculation mode is already set to Automatic and F9 doesn't work. The problem is the cell in the tab "CO" where i call the data with "=(Dati!C6)" from another tab "Data" doesn't update until i press (F2+Enter) on it.

Comment: Try using Ctrl-Alt-F9. Another workaround is the Find & Replace “=“ with “=“ in all formulas.

Comment: What is the format of those cells? make sure they are in General format, so the formulas can be recognized properly. Also, if you share the file, maybe we can find out more. Now everything are shots in the dark.

Comment: @DS_London using Ctrl-Alt-F9 after opening the file the cells has updated. It's work. Thanks

Comment: This is a handy primer on how Excel works out what & when to calculate: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel-recalculation

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you wish to process and  this:

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each r In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
            r.Select
            Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
            Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
            DoEvents
        Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```